# Iptables: NAT postrouting table skipped altogether

Tags: iptables, nat

While playing around with keeplived, I came across  this weird (or is it?) behaviour.

The scenario is as follows:

An internal network  that has a gateway  ( call it gw ) and a bunch of hosts (one of them called ih1) .
Another host (call it ha) that has 2 interfaces : one in the public network a second in the internal one.
An external host (eh1)

[ha] is a keepalived instance to route traffic to internal hosts that offer a service says smtp.
[ih1] is an smpt server,  it's default gateway is [gw]

from [eh1]
nc [ha] 25  doesn't work, and if fails in a manner I didn't expect at all.

When the initial packet hits [ih1] it replies through its default gateway, [eh1] receives the reply but the strange thing is instead of the public ip of [gw] ( as one would expect because [gw] is supposed to be masquerading) it gets a reply with the actual ip address of [ih1]. i.e :  [gw] is forwarding the packets, not masquerading them. 
Of course [eh] has no idea how to reach directly [ih1] so it fails to establish a connection.

Digging yields that all packets originating from [ih1] in reply to [eh] request are not going through the POSTROUTING chain of iptable's nat table.

But if [ih1] initiates the connection (say ping [eh1] or ssh [eh1] ) it works as it is supposed to.

Comparing both situations the only thing that jumps to mind is in the first [gw] never say the initial SYN packet, all it saw was SYN/ACK reply.

EDIT:
where I_LAN is internal lan : 172.16.0.0/24 and E_LAN is external lan : 192.168.0.0/24

```
    [eh1]-- E_LAN --
                               ---------
       ---E_LAN--[ha]--I_LAN--| switch  |--I_LAN--[gw]--ELAN--
                               ---------
                                   |
                                 [ih1]
```

Comment: From the description, it sounds that [ha] is directly connected to WAN bypassing the gateway?... Could you draw the layout? I have a feeling that alone would point out the problem.

Comment: sure, will do. I was planing on tagging packets on [ih1] to route them back through [ha]. I just decided to test out and see what happens, and I was intreaged byt the result. 
and yes [ha] is directly connected to WAN.

Comment: Well there you go – if packets from WAN to directly to [ha], bypassing the regular gateway, then _of course_ the gateway won't see the SYNs.

Comment: that I knew.  I question is I guess, is that reason enough to bypass the nat table. Most site speak of INITIAL packet (no specifying what type) passing through NAT POSTROUTING. what  about UDP (no syn packet there)  ...  the behavior seems odd to me !!